# Echo Nest track ID to Spotify URI conversion

Tags: spotify, echonest

I'd like to use Echo Nest's API to get tracks and play them in Spotify, but I couldn't find a nice way to get the Spotify track URI from the Echo Nest's track ID. One roundabout way would be to grab the artist/track name from an Echo Nest's track response and look up songs that match using Spotify's metadata API, but I feel like there should be a better way, especially since Spotify's native radio app is powered by Echo Nest.

[Project Rosetta Stone](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4#project-rosetta-stone) offers some conversions from Echo Nest's ID to other ID spaces but Spotify is not included in there. Any ideas how this conversion might be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Now it's possible: http://blog.echonest.com/post/20116429399/spotify-the-echo-nest-api-spotify-apps-just-got

---

The Spotify's radio app is powered by this api: http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/playlist.html and a private bucket...

> One roundabout way would be to grab the artist/track name from an Echo Nest's track response and look up songs that match using Spotify's metadata API

That's the unique way.